# Origin of Shiva aavahan mantra?

Tags: shiva, mantras, reference-request, source

The Shiva Aavahan mantra recites:

> शिव आह्वाहन मंत्र
>
> ॐ मृत्युंजय परेशान जगदाभयनाशन ।
> तव ध्यानेन देवेश मृत्युप्राप्नोति जीवती ।।
>
> वन्दे ईशान देवाय नमस्तस्मै पिनाकिने ।
> आदिमध्यांत रूपाय मृत्युनाशं करोतु मे ।।
>
> नमस्तस्मै भगवते कैलासाचल वासिने ।
> नमोब्रह्मेन्द्र रूपाय मृत्युनाशं करोतु मे ।।
>
> त्र्यंबकाय नमस्तुभ्यं पंचस्याय नमोनमः ।
> नमो दोर्दण्डचापाय मम मृत्युम् विनाशय ।।
>
> नमोर्धेन्दु स्वरूपाय नमो दिग्वसनाय च ।
> नमो भक्तार्ति हन्त्रे च मम मृत्युं विनाशय ।।
>
> देवं मृत्युविनाशनं भयहरं साम्राज्य मुक्ति प्रदम् ।
> नाना भूतगणान्वितं दिवि पदैः देवैः सदा सेवितम् ।।
>
> अज्ञानान्धकनाशनं शुभकरं विध्यासु सौख्य प्रदम् ।
> सर्व सर्वपति महेश्वर हरं मृत्युंजय भावये ।।
>
> Om mrityunjay pareshaan jagadaabhayanaashan
> Tav dhyaanen devesh mrityupraapnoti jeevati
>
> Vande ishaan devaay namastasmai pinakine
> Aadimadhyaant rupaay mrityunaasham karotu me
>
> Namastasmai bhagwate kailasachal vaasine
> Namobrahmendra rupaay mrityunaasham karotu
>
> Trayambakaya namastubhyam panchasyaay namo namah
> Namo dordandachaapaay mam mrityum vinaashay
>
> Namordhendu swarupaay Namo digvasanaay cha
> Namo Bhaktarti hantre cha mam mrityum vinaashay
>
> Devam mrituvinaashanam bhayaharam saamrajya mukti pradam
> Nana bhutagananvitam divi padaih devaih sada sevitam
>
> Agyaanaandhakanaashanam shubhkaram vidhyaasu saukhya pradam
> Sarv sarvapati maheshwara haram mrityunjay bhaavaye

Who composed this mantra in form of a stotram? What is its origin?